# Change of Basis between different dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

Changing basis from 3 dimension to 2 dimension is possible?

I’ve been trying to solve this but I couldn’t get this. Please help me!!

Comment: These kind of maps aren't change of basis. However, every matrix which is *surjective* maps your basis in the input space to a generating set (which is a basis with possibly redundant elements) in the output space. Is there anything particular you have in mind?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I have no idea about this... because my professor didn’t explain this he told us he would explain after but he didn’t.

Comment: Can you guys help me out...?

Comment: Hansoo, they did not ask for a change of basis between different dimensions. They asked for the change of basis matrix between $B$ and $B'$. They also asked for the change of basis matrix between $C$ and $C'$, in part 3. It looks like a homework. I am sorry I cannot solve it for you, but I can explain a little.

Comment: For 1, if you have a linear transformation from a vector space $V_1$ to another $V_2$, and if you have bases $B_1$ and $B_2$ of $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively, then you can define a matrix which represents this linear transformation with respect to the bases $B_1$ and $B_2$. This is explained in Linear Algebra textbooks. Look at your textbook.

Comment: It’s not my homework.. just one of the exercise. Tomorrow I have an exam in University and this is the last I have to know. As I said my profesor gave us just a formular but I don’t understand...

Comment: The answer is (1 -1) and I don’t know how it can be 1x2 matrix

Comment: it has $1$ row and $2$ columns, so it is a $1\times2$ matrix.

Comment: What I mean is where (1, -1) this come from...

Comment: ok, I will help with part 1 only.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

$$T\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right),$$ and
$$T\left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) = -\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right).$$

So the image of the first basis element of $B$ is just the basis element of $C$. Thus the first column of the $1 \times 2$ matrix is $(1)$. Similarly, the image of the second basis element of $B$ is minus the basis element of $C$, so the second column of the $1 \times 2$ matrix representing $T$ with respect to $B$ and $C$ is $(-1)$. Hence $T$ is represented by $(1 -1)$ with respect to the bases $B$ and $C$. This is the answer to part $1$. I hope this helps. Good luck preparing for your exam.

Comment: Sir can you explain me the reason? I don’t understand  why you put -1 for the second element. And we can use the same vector for both?

Comment: Look at the definition of $T$. Set $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: For the last thing I want to do more exercise of this could you let me know what should I search for this?

Comment: Thank you for helping me